# Why does this code crash when I declare one more variable?

Tags: c, compiler-construction, struct, scanf

Here's my code. It works when I comment out the "luetut" variable.
But when I compile as follows, I get segmentation fault when the program should print the variables. What sense does this make? When I try to make a debug build, something totally weird shows up (multiple definition of this and that).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct rakenne
{
    int luku;
    float liukuluku;
    char* mjono;
}   Rakenne;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int luetut = 0;
    Rakenne palikka;
//  Rakenne palikka, *palikkaosoitin;
//  palikkaosoitin = &palikka;

//  while(luetut < 1)
//  {
        printf("Anna luku:\n");
        scanf("%d", &palikka.luku);
//  }   luetut = 0;
//  while(luetut < 1)
//  {
        printf("Anna liukuluku:\n");
        scanf("%f", &palikka.liukuluku);
//  }   luetut = 0;
    printf("Anna merkkijono:\n");
    scanf("%s", palikka.mjono);

    printf("%i\t%.3f\t%s\n", palikka.luku, palikka.liukuluku, palikka.mjono);

    return 0;
}
```

So, is my gcc compiler broken or what could be the problem?

Comment: Don't forget to test whether `scanf()` successfully read a value each time you use it.

Comment: If you are posting code, please make it as clean as possible... i.e. remove the unnecessary commented-out code.

Answer (score 4):

> ```
> scanf("%s", palikka.mjono);
> ```

You didn't make `mjono` point to anything so writing to it is of course illegal - undefined behavior. Doing something like this leads to erratic behavior: the program "works" or "fails" for no apparent reason.

---

> So, is my gcc compiler broken or what could be the problem

It's rarely constructive to think the tools you are using are the problem.

Comment: Adding to cnicutar's point: you should assume the compiler is perfectly correct for a very long time yet.  Although compilers are not bug free, it is extremely unlikely that you'll run into a bug in one while you're learning C.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I changed the string variable into char* mjono[]; and it doesn't crash anymore.

Comment: " I changed the string variable into char* mjono[]; and it doesn't crash anymore." It may not crash anymore, but it is still wrong. Now you've got an array of pointers, and still no memory allocated for a string.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on [cnicutars](https://stackoverflow.com/users/714501/cnicutar) answer, the fix would be to allocate some memory for `palikka.mjono`.

Something like this:

```
#define SIZE     40   // or whatever you need.
palikka.mjono = malloc( sizeof(char) * SIZE );
```

Then later don't forget to `free` that memory:

```
free( palikka.mjono );
```

Or if you know what the maximum size of your strings will be, just define your structure as:

```
typedef struct rakenne
{
    int luku;
    float liukuluku;
    char mjono[SIZE];
}   Rakenne;
```